# Calling JSON.deserialize() throws "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Tags: json, exception, apexrest, null-pointer, deserialize

I'm trying to use the System method `JSON.deserialize(jsonString, apexType)` to deserialize the body of an ApexRest POST request.  My code compiles, but at runtime I'm getting a `System.NullPointerException` from the line making the `JSON.deserialize()` call.

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
RestRequest req         = RestContext.request;
String      jsonString  = req.requestBody.toString();
System.Type myType      = System.Type.forName('PostDataWrapper');

// This next line throws a System.NullPointerException
PostDataWrapper postData = (PostDataWrapper)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, myType);
```

I've confirmed that the `requestBody` body has the correct JSON payload, and I'm sure that I have a `PostDataWrapper` type because it's declared in the ApexRest class itself as an inner class.

Where is the `System.NullPointerException` coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the value passed to the `System.Type.forName()` call.

This method requires a "fully qualified" class name.  Since the `PostDataWrapper` class was declared as an inner class, you need to prepend the name of the outer class to the string parameter.

If the outer class was  named `MyRestClass`, then your call would look like this:

```
System.Type myType = (PostDataWrapper)System.Type.forName('MyRestClass.PostDataWrapper');
```

Calling the `System.Type.forName()` method with the correct, "fully qualified" type name should place a non-null value into the `myType` variable. This should allow the call to `JSON.deserialize()` to succeed (assuming there aren't any serialization errors).